# Delete line from grid in axapta

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm quite new in Axapta and I didn't get how I can to delete selected line from grid, actually my problem is that I cant get selected line, so how should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you have a `Data source` node, here you have your `Data source` to use to display data in **form** in methods you have `Delete()` method. This method is called when you delete record. Also you can override this method.

If you press **ALT + F9** in one line you can delete this line. The method `Delete()` of `Data source` is called.

You can create a `CommandButton` to delete records in grid, in `Command property` set `Delete Register`. Also you can create a button and call the method `Delete()` of your `Data Source`.

In all cases the record of the selected line is deleted.

Comment: and if I want to open selected record in another form how should I do that how should I get object which is selected

Comment: ok, the title of this question is **Delete line form grid in axapta**. For this new question it is better to create a new question. but quick response create `MenuItemButton` in `DataSource` property set your data source and `MenuItemButton` property set the `MenuItem` of new form.